# REST service project structure

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was working on a project with a colleague and he told me that I should create 3 levels when creating a rest service. Can anyone explain me if this is the 'normal' and if I use it in the correct way? He never explained me why and left the firm a few weeks later.

**First level: Resource**

> I imagine this is where you catch the requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc.)

**Second level: Service**

> I would make sense that calculations happen here?

**Third level: Repository**

> This is where he put all the statements that connect with the
>   Database.

e.g. Say we have an entity 'Employee' with a property 'level'. Depending on your level, you get a different bonus. We want to calculate the bonus and return it via a REST service.

The resource method would look something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/id/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public double findBonusById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return employeeService.findBonusById(id);
}
```

The service method would look something like this:

```
public double findBonusById(long id) {
    int level = employeeRepository.findLevelById(id);
    double initialBonus = 2563;
    return level * initialBonus;
}
```

The repository method would look something like this:

```
public int findLevelById(long id) {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Employee.findLevelById").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: The proper term for your levels are [layers](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/software-architecture-patterns/page/2/layered-architecture).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is called layered architecture, in your case

**Controller** which handles the request

```
@GET
@Path("/id/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public double findBonusById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
return employeeService.findBonusById(id);
}
```

**Service**  is a layer which communicates between controller and Repository

```
public double findBonusById(long id) {
int level = employeeRepository.findLevelById(id);
double initialBonus = 2563;
return level * initialBonus;
}
```

**Business** This is optional layer and depends on requirement, you can have all your business logic in this layer

```
double initialBonus = 2563;
return level * initialBonus;
```

**Repository** this is as you said `This is where he put all the statements that connect with the Database.`

```
public int findLevelById(long id) {
return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Employee.findLevelById").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain a scenario where a business layer would be useful? It seems to do the same as the service layer.

Comment: if you have huge business scenarios, assume you have `List` of 2000 business records and you need to perform different action on each object by grouping them based on data. in this case where do you do that action? in the service layer making it mess?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Matthijs, that's normal. While building any webservice related projects what people prefer is different "layer" of separation. i.e 
[layer architecture](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch01.html)

1. Controller :- where your request lands.

   `@GET
   @Path("/id/{id}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public double findBonusById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
       return employeeService.findBonusById(id);
   }`
2. Service :- where you perform business logic

   `public double findBonusById(long id) {
       int level = employeeRepository.findLevelById(id);
       double initialBonus = 2563;
       return level * initialBonus;
   }`
3. Repository :- where you communicate to your database.

   `public int findLevelById(long id) {
       return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Employee.findLevelById").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
   }`

These are some of the standard which normally people follow however there can be more layer of separation.